# Rails slow view rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, rendering

Does this console output look normal?

16:10:01 rails.1 | Started GET "/" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-11-01 16:10:01
+0000 16:10:02 rails.1 | Processing by PagesController#home as HTML 16:10:02 rails.1 |    (1.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "parks" 16:10:02 rails.1 |    (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trains" WHERE "trains"."superseded_at" IS NULL 16:10:02 rails.1 |   Train Load (10.9ms)  SELECT "trains".* FROM "trains"  ORDER BY "trains"."train_sort" ASC 16:10:02 rails.1 |   Cycle Load (26.6ms) SELECT "cycles".* FROM "cycles" WHERE "cycles"."train_id" IN (22147, 21958, 22055, 22059, 22356, 22045, 22001, 22072, 21836, 22000, 21800, 22042, 22373, 21818, 22024, 22364, 22365, 22168, 21863, 22242, 22054, 22060, 21899, 22392, 22117, 21920, 21822, 22354, 22401, 21931, 21826, 21834, 22306, 21970, 21980, 21791, 21790, 21961, 22037, 21955, 21985, 22191, 22391, 21870, 22004, 22180, 22164, 22383, 22405, 22161, 22169, 22254, 21812, 22031, 22219, 22063, 21873, 22028, 22232, 21942, 22175, 21953, 21787, 22251, 21900, 22206, 21805, 21793, 22390, 22066, 21783, 22376, 22083, 22415, 22346, 21913, 21932, 22011, 22394, 22250, 21866, 22328, 22324, 21839, 21939, 22021, 22087, 22290, 22027, 21993, 22065, 22187, 22278, 21902, 21861, 21963, 21952, 22304, 22293, 22284, 22279, 22269, 21848, 21788, 21855, 21854, 22209, 21857, 21784, 22188, 22178, 22181, 22166, 22146, 21883, 22239, 22137, 22135, 21903, 22133, 22127, 22099, 22098, 22095, 22090, 21912, 22096, 22398, 22397, 22222, 21937, 21936, 22006, 21998, 22361, 22380, 22023, 21979, 21810, 22351, 22204, 22357, 22396, 22240, 22198, 22208, 22211, 21926, 22139, 22294, 22297, 22026, 22344, 21959, 22082, 22094, 22067, 21974, 22106, 22126, 22277, 21809, 22141, 22384, 22234, 22404, 22243, 22049, 21881, 22409, 22159, 21829, 21846, 21885, 21878, 21890, 21897, 21910, 21919, 22221, 22228, 21934, 21935, 21977, 21994, 22044, 22051, 22046, 22047, 22062, 22084, 22103, 22109, 22123, 22116, 22121, 22124, 22237, 22241, 22142, 22184, 22189, 22196, 21789, 22255, 22256, 22314, 22368, 22371, 22411, 21992, 22104, 22100, 22056, 22322, 22020, 22165, 22203, 22010, 22227, 22149, 22015, 22353, 22275, 21880, 22274, 22032, 22064, 21989, 22310, 22330, 22245, 21823, 22183, 22374, 21884, 21908, 22119, 22105, 22025, 22319, 21838, 22002, 22048, 21850, 21865, 22085, 22143, 22285, 21924, 22102, 22323, 22073, 21909, 21786, 22318, 22151, 22077, 21799, 22113, 22316, 21803, 22308, 22289, 21840, 22271, 22366, 22185, 21951, 21871, 21945, 21802, 22199, 22336, 22007, 21796, 22343, 22387, 21916, 22305, 22195, 22338, 22226, 22192, 22249, 22217, 22130, 22120, 22296, 22307, 21990, 22043, 21987, 21907, 22138, 21815, 22112, 22231, 21949, 21978, 21950, 21969, 22375, 22367, 22362, 21940, 21933, 21930, 21929, 22332, 22016, 22327, 22019, 22298, 22038, 21923, 22268, 21804, 22229, 22267, 22259, 22253, 21851, 21853, 22194, 22068, 21869, 22190, 22160, 22079, 22148, 22402, 22236, 22097, 21915, 22101, 22128, 22129, 22400, 22111, 21828, 21896, 22281, 21794, 22320, 21797, 22326, 21806, 21981, 21964, 22378, 22370, 22013, 22291, 22295, 22093, 22122, 21795, 22108, 22272, 21921, 22340, 22012, 22399, 22110, 22299, 22286, 22041, 22218, 21798, 22177, 22089, 21967, 21886, 22282, 21960, 22359, 22358, 21821, 22395, 21971, 22207, 21973, 21876, 22408, 22174, 22125, 21898, 22091, 22238, 22403, 22248, 21887, 22144, 22081, 22076, 21891, 22170, 22173, 21874, 22176, 22182, 21867, 22406, 22197, 22200, 22205, 21986, 22058, 21847, 21792, 22057, 21845, 22263, 22407, 22260, 22270, 22266, 22393, 21844, 22280, 22030, 22309, 21982, 22018, 22342, 21824, 21946, 21827, 21819, 21999, 22413, 22369, 22414, 21817, 21814, 22381, 22389, 22382, 21997, 21954, 22115, 21905, 21860, 21901, 22311, 22193, 22230, 22313, 21991, 21816, 22363, 22114, 21938, 22186, 22179, 21928, 21983, 22360, 22022, 22092, 21864, 21831, 22074, 22257, 22003, 22131, 22388, 21894, 22349, 22337, 22348, 21996, 22140, 21825, 22347, 21966, 22132, 22345, 22352, 22152, 22202, 22210, 22075, 22088, 22172, 22134, 22118, 22086, 22171, 21922, 22107, 21917, 21868, 21879, 22158, 22386, 22157, 21841, 21957, 22163, 21842, 21843, 22155, 22220, 22287, 22040, 22069, 22201, 22071, 22061, 22078, 21895, 22053, 21914, 22212, 22080, 22300, 22412, 22213, 22301, 22154, 22153, 21832, 21801, 22145, 21906, 21911, 21995, 22224, 21904, 21856, 21852, 22252, 22385, 22264, 22052, 21984, 22235, 21811, 22246, 21956, 21892, 22288, 22039, 21888, 21837, 22292, 22036, 22035, 21968, 22303, 22034, 21925, 21941, 22312, 21927, 22321, 22317, 21962, 22325, 22331, 22329, 22339, 21813, 21877, 21875, 21976, 22410, 22225, 22247, 22215, 22335, 21965, 22341, 22233, 22334, 22005, 22333, 22315, 21988, 22029, 21835, 21858, 22276, 22050, 21862, 21882, 22273, 22262, 22261, 22265, 21872, 21785, 22009, 21947, 21893, 22214, 21944, 21820, 22008, 22216, 22302, 22033, 22223, 21972, 22156, 21849, 22377, 22162, 22070, 21948, 22167, 22136, 22355, 22350, 22379, 21830, 21975, 22372, 21943, 22258, 22017, 21918, 21859, 21808, 21889, 21807, 22283, 22150, 22244, 22014, 21833) 16:10:02 rails.1 |    (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "photos" 16:10:03 rails.1 |   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms) 16:10:03 rails.1 |   Rendered shared/_svg.html.erb (0.6ms) 16:10:03 rails.1 |   Rendered shared/_svg.html.erb (0.1ms) 16:10:04 rails.1 |   Rendered shared/_banner_slideshow.html.erb (0.1ms) 16:10:04 rails.1 |   Rendered shared/_flash_messages.html.erb (0.4ms) 16:10:04 rails.1 |   Rendered shared/_svg.html.erb (0.1ms) 16:10:04 rails.1 |   Rendered shared/_svg.html.erb (0.1ms) 16:10:04 rails.1 |   Rendered shared/_svg.html.erb (0.1ms) 16:10:04 rails.1 |   Rendered shared/_svg.html.erb (0.1ms) 16:10:04 rails.1 |   Rendered shared/_svg.html.erb (0.1ms) 16:10:04 rails.1 | Completed 200 OK in 2414ms (Views: 2033.0ms | ActiveRecord: 40.6ms)

Why do the individual parts of the render take less than 1ms but then the total Views rendering is over 2 seconds?

home.html.erb: - I emptied this out to see if something in here was cuaisng the slowness but even with this outputting a single word the total view render is over 2 seconds.

```
blah
```

_svg.html.erb:

```
<svg role="img" aria-labelledby="title desc" class="<%= classs if local_assigns[:classs] %>">
  <% if local_assigns[:title] %>
    <title id="title"><%= title %></title>
  <% end %>
  <% if local_assigns[:description] %>
    <desc id="desc"><%= description %></desc>
  <% end %>
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#<%= hash %>"></use>
</svg>
```

_banner-slideshow.html.erb:

```
<div class="gallery banner banner--slideshow">
  <div class="gallery__slide"></div>
  <div class="gallery__slide"></div>
  <div class="gallery__slide"></div>
  <div class="gallery__slide"></div>
</div>
```

_flash-messages.html.erb:

```
<% if flash.any? %>
  <% flash.each do |type, message| %>
    <%= render partial: 'shared/flash_message', locals: { type: type, message: message } %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

_flash-message.html.erb:

```
<div class="message-box message-box--<%= type %>">
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
  <%= message %>
</div>
```

Comment: can you paste the views? maybe the problem is N+1 queries inside the views

Comment: @matanco Added views to OP

Answer (score 0):

you can improve your code by reduce the call's to subviews in  `_flash-messages.html.erb`:

```
<% if flash.any? %>    
    <%= render partial: 'shared/flash_message', locals: { flash: flash } %>
<% end %>
```

then in your `_flash-message.html.erb`:

```
<% flash.each do |type, message| %>
  <div class="message-box message-box--<%= type %>">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
    <%= message %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

this will reduce the sub-views rendering and will take less time to finish the job.

Comment: I've modified those partials which is great but its had no effect on the view rendering times. The console output is stating all the partials are taking 0.xms to load but the collective totals underneath is stating `Completed 200 OK in 4139ms (Views: 3034.1ms | ActiveRecord: 42.9ms)`. Surely this isn't right. This is a tiny page doing nothing in comparison to other applications. Any other ideas about where to look? This issue is driving me insane. There has to be something wrong somewhere.